# Use local repo in satis repository

Tags: git, composer-php, satis

I have a server in which I have a few git repos and a satis repository setup. I'd like to setup the satis repository to list the local repos.

```
// satis.json
{
  "name": "NJ16 Repositories",
  "homepage": "http://packages.example.com",
  "repositories": [
        { 
            "type": "vcs", 
            "url": "https://bitbucket.org/nicholasjohn16/example.git" 
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@example.com:/var/repo/test-repo.git"
        }
  ],
  "require-all": true,
  "output-dir": "web/"
}
```

When I run this, the bitbucket git repo is accessed and updated successfully, but when satis gets to building the local git repo it hangs at the following lines and doesn't continue.

```
Executing command (/root/.cache/composer/vcs/git-example.com--repo-test-repo.git): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/root/.cache/composer/vcs/git-example.com--repo-test-repo.git): git remote -v
Executing command (/root/.cache/composer/vcs/git-example.com--repo-test-repo.git): git remote set-url origin 'git@example.com:/repo/test-repo.git' && git remote update --prune origin
```

I've tried using `../../repo/test-repo.git` and `/var/repo/test-repo.git` for the repo url. When I do this, the build completes successfully, but when I try to require it with composer, I get the following error.

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                      
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout  "C:\wamp\www\nj16\nicholasjohn16\vendor\NicholasJohn16\test-repo" && cd /D "C:\wamp\www\nj16\nicholasjohn16\vendor\NicholasJohn16\test-repo" && git remote add composer  && git fetch composer

Cloning into 'test-repo'...                         
fatal: 'C:\wamp\www\nj16\nicholasjohn16\vendor\NicholasJohn16\test-repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                           

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Though, it does make reference to the most recent commit hash so I know it's atleast fetching the repo successfully, but satis doesn't seem to have access to the data.

How can I do this correct? Any assistance is appreciated.

JFYI, `git` is a user and has their own ssh key which is added to `authorized_users` so they can clone their own repo.

Comment: What do you get when you run `$ git clone --no-checkoutgit@example.com:/var/repo/test-repo.git` ?

Comment: Locally on my pc, I get a copy of the bare repo. Or do you mean on the server?

Comment: So no errors about athentication or anything?

Comment: Nope, no errors.

Answer (score -1):

Hi please make sure your are running proper command and path

then fallow below path

please go to you repo path (`C:\wamp\www\nj16\nicholasjohn16\vendor\NicholasJohn16\test-repo`)

And initialize the empty repository

`git init`

then set a remote also iy you want then
`git remote add composer github-url`

Then add a branch if requires

`git branch slave`

**Then checkout to slave branch**

Then use

> Note 1: please run one after one then you will get know what is the failure is
>
> Note 2 : please re check your command which your running
>
> Note 3 : fallow my steps

Comment: Thanks, but that's not right. The vendor directory is managed by composer, not git. Composer should be loading the dependency there.